# CISCO IOS's feature Secure Shell Version 2 Enhancements for RSA Keys

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst, ssh

I have a switch C3750V2-48PS with IOS ver. 12.2(55)SE5. I wanted to copy to it public key for the ssh client but I do not have following command available

```
Switch#configure terminal
Switch(config)#ip ssh pubkey-chain
```

according to the link [HERE](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_usr_ssh/configuration/15-s/sec-usr-ssh-15-s-book/sec-secure-shell-v2.html) it is available from IOS versions:

> Cisco IOS 15.0(1)M
>
> Cisco IOS 15.1(1)S

I found out that there is IOS update available for my switch [HERE](https://software.cisco.com/download/home/282526574/type/280805680/release/15.0.2-SE11?i=!pp), which is:

> 15.0.2-SE11(MD)

However, after a while of web browsing I do not know how to verify whether the command is available in that IOS.
Feature name is:

> Secure Shell Version 2 Enhancements for RSA Keys.

Can anyone tell me how to list/check all the available commands on specific IOS without installing it, please?

Comment: Might be helpful to decipher versioning [HERE](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-release-1513t/200095-Understanding-Cisco-IOS-Naming-Conventio.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cisco maintains the [*Cisco Feature Navigator*](http://cfn.cloudapps.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/index.jsp) page where you can look up which features are available for which hardware or OS versions.

It doesn't appear that what you are looking for is available for that switch, which is past "*The last date that Cisco Engineering may release any final software maintenance releases or bug fixes. After this date, Cisco Engineering will no longer develop, repair, maintain, or test the product software.*" (May 14, 2017).

Comment: CFN is a bit hit-or-miss. doubly so for switches. (eg. "warm reload" on a 2960S)

Comment: @RickyBeam have you got an idea how can I check it then? I wrote to Cisco but they require my customerID which I simply do not have.

Comment: Load various version of IOS and see for yourself.